# How to fix this int is not subscriptable on my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a question for my assignment.It prints the names with the highest numbers in descending order. I did it like the teacher showed in class. But I keep getting the int is not subscriptable in line 15. What did I do wrong?

The question for reference:

Suppose a list contains marks earned in the courses CSE110, PHY111, and MAT110 of each student consecutively in a nested list form. Your task is to take a course name as input from the user and sort the list based on the marks obtained in that course in order to finally print the names of the students in descending order of marks obtained i.e. from the student who earned the highest marks to the student who earned the lowest.

For example, the list may look like
lst = [ ["Alan", 95, 87, 91], ["Turing", 92, 90, 83], ["Elon", 87, 92, 80], ["Musk", 85, 94, 90] ]
where for each nested list, 1st index holds the name of the student, 2nd index is total marks earned in the CSE110 course, 3rd index is PHY111 marks and 4th index is MAT110 marks.

=====================================================

```
Sample Input :
MAT110
```

```
Sample Output :
Alan
Musk
Turing
Elon
```

The Error :

```
Enter Desired Course Name: PHY111

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-18-b99751889edb> in <module>()
     13 
     14 for i in range(0, len(org_list)):
---> 15     best = org_list[i][index]
     16     best_loc = i
     17     mod_list = org_list[i]

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

```
org_list = [ ["Alan", 95, 87, 91], ["Turing", 92, 90, 83], ["Elon", 87, 92, 80], ["Musk", 85, 94, 90] ]

course = input('Enter Desired Course Name: ')

if course == 'CSE110':
    index = 1
elif course == 'PHY111':
    index = 2
elif course == 'MAT110':
    index = 3

for i in range(0, len(org_list)):
    best = org_list[i][index]
    best_loc = i
    mod_list = org_list[i]

    for i in range(i+1, len(org_list)):
        if best < org_list[i][index]:
            best = org_list[i][index]
            best_loc = i

    interim = mod_list
    org_list[best_loc] = org_list[i]
    org_list = interim

for count in range(0, len(org_list)):
    print(org_list[count][0])
```

Comment: You reuse the `org_list` variable at the line: `org_list = interim`. Now `org_list` refers to a sublist and `orig_list[i]` will be one of the integers in the list.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Quickly, well you're overriding `org_list` in that for loop.

Comment: At the end of the for loop you're reassigning `org_list` to be something else, so you get the error on the next loop iteration .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as someone mentioned I made the mistake in the last line.

it should be:

```
org_list[i] = interim
```

it was:

```
 org_list = interim
```

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what this program is supposed to do but the problem is in these lines:

```
interim = mod_list
...
org_list = mod_list
```

You previously extracted a sublist from `org_list`, i.e., `mod_list` is not a nested list but `["Alan", 95, 87, 91]` for the first loop execution.

Now, you overwrite `org_list` with one of the sublists. But then, in the next loop execution you fail to access a nested list with `org_list[i][index]`.

Comment: `I'm not sure what this program is supposed to do`: this was before you clarified it :-)